# Category name on post

Tags: laravel

On my posts page, I want to display the category name rather than the ID. I've tried searching and trying every solution I can find here but still struggling, so any help would be massively appreciated.

In my policy resource controller, I have:

```
public function show(Policy $policy)
{
    return view('policies.show',compact('policy'));
}
```

In my Policy model, I've got.

```
public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

I've got `cat_id` in my policies table, and in my categories table, it is id and category_name. So, of course, I can show the category ID on the policy page by doing the following.

```
{{ $policy->cat_id }}
```

But I need to convert that into the category name. I know this is a basic question, but I've only recently started getting into Laravel. I have done a lot of searching, and none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: `{{ $policy-> category-> category_name ?? '' }}` use this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This displays nothing for me.

Comment: In your blade you can debug the values with `@dd($policy->category)`. You may want to eager load the categories relation in your controller or Policy model. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks for this. when debugging, I'm getting null... So I'm assuming this is my problem. Just can't figure out why it's null?! Sorry to be such a pain, but really appreciate the support

Comment: Since you didn't fully follow naming convention, you'r relation should be `return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'cat_id');`. This should solve your issue. Following recommendations is highly advised. Check [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) for good practices.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for the link on good practices too. Really appreciate that.